# Numbering and referring sections in bookdown

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown

I use bookdown for writing a report in Word, and I cannot find a way to number the sections of my report (or to refer to them). Here is a minimal example:

```
---
output:
  bookdown::word_document2
---

## Section 1

## Section 2
```

[image]

As far as I can see, the solutions refer to HTML documents only as explained [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can [change the style in Word](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Number-your-headings-CE24E028-4CB4-4D4A-BF25-FB2C61FC6585) and then use the resulting document as your [reference_docx](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/word-document.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, as far as I understand, this is a change you can only apply after you have "knitted" the Word document from RStudio. I would like to change the settings from my document while it is still an rmarkdown file.

Comment: It's a mix of both, really. You'll have to make a change outside of RStudio, but only once. Later invocations can then used the altered document. It's a one-off change. There is currently [no other method](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1413), unfortunately.